# Azure WAF Issue with WebSocket (OmniFaces )

Tags: azure, iis, websocket, omnifaces, azure-waf

I have a OmniFaces WebSocket deployed on tomcat. The WebSocket works fine on tomcat.

One of our client infrastructure setup is Azure WAF --> IIS --> Tomcat.
We have successfully tested the WebSocket from IIS to Tomcat.

When we test from Azure WAF , we have a successful handshake (Upgrade request) , but the browser does not receive any of the push message. Microsoft claims the WebSocket are default supported in Azure WAF and no setup changes are required.

It looks more like a Azure WAF issue and I am not sure  how to debug the issue.
Any suggestion or idea to debug this issue ?